# Is body building feasible for vegetarians?

Tags: sports, lacto-vegetarianism

Every athlete and bodybuilder talks about regimes and diets that are non-vegetarian.
Is it possible for vegetarians to beat a non-vegetarian diet? If so, how?
What are the replacements of high-protein foods and supplements that one would use?

It would be great if you could suggest some particular diet. I have tried chickpeas, kidney beans, gram and several kinds of lentils but I experience gas sometimes. Is there a better option or is the way they should be prepared that ensures gas can be prevented?

Comment: it's not every athlete and bodybuilder for sure :) There are many veg\*n athletes and body builders. So the answer to your question is just "yes". Can you make it more specific to get a better answer? See [Are there any well known vegan athletes?](//vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/1074) - if vegans can do it, then vegetarians can too haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any well known vegan athletes?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/are-there-any-well-known-vegan-athletes)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. This asks about "feasibility" (which I translate to "healthy" and/or "sustainable"), not to provide a list of vegan athletes. Maybe it can be rephrased to explicitly tackle the healthy aspect.

Comment: You can't really mark a dupe of a closed question...

Comment: I think it's not worth an anwser, but have a look at: http://www.greatveganathletes.com/

Comment: Are you asking about strict vegetarianism (fully plant-based aka vegan) or are you asking about a diet that includes eggs and/or dairy?

Comment: I was asking about veg + lactic.

Comment: This is sort of two questions - "what kind of vegetarian diet is useful for body-building?" and "is there a way to prepare legumes that reduces gas?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You totally can be a vegetarian and a body builder. I've been a body builder for 35 years and a vegetarian for about 7 or 8 years. I feel much better meatless and my workouts have never suffered.

There are good sources of plant based protein meals out there, such as potatoes and corn or rice and black beans. In combination these meals have a complete amino acid profile. Plus you can get extra protein from plant based raw protein powder. I am very happy with the one from Sunwarrior (rice, chia, pea, quinoa and amaranth). Comes as blends or only rice protein. All in raw food quality and sweetened with stevia.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what everyone is saying above. If you have not heard of Kendrick Farris or his story as a vegan lifter, you should check it out. He puts to rest a lot of stereotypes and misconceptions about veganism. In addition, he let's you in on his diet and how he builds muscles with plant protein. Here is the [link](https://www.holonis.com/sports/p/kendrick-farris-shares-his-lifechanging-fitness-tips-for-vegan-lifters) to the article.

Comment: Hello there :) This read more like a comment than an answer. The information about the Kendrick Farris is definitely interesting but in the current form, the answer as a whole lacks some more content that would address questions specifically asked by the OP. Would you care to elaborate here a bit? :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally consume 2.4 L of raw milk yogurt (although I wouldn't advise anyone about the raw part unless you know you're getting the milk from a trusted farmer and you have a good enough immune system to handle possible pathogens in raw milk) which gives me about 70-80 grams of protein. I also consume 300 grams of whole wheat flour fermented using sourdough culture which gives me about 40 grams of protein. Both of these are high quality, highly bioavailable protein sources (the sourdough fermentation breaks down any anti-nutrients in the flour such as gluten and oxalates). In addition, I also consume plenty of fruits which gives me about 5-10 grams of protein. Coincidentally, this also covers almost all the micros too.

All in all, I'm quite easily able to get about 120 grams of protein and almost all the micros I need from this kind of a vegetarian diet. So diet-wise, there's certainly no restraint from not eating meat/eggs as regards to getting enough protein as well as your micros. Which in turn means that there shouldn't be any restraint in being able to build muscle when such a diet is combined with a bodybuilding routine.